# Is Glance visible immediately on Apple Watch?

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

I read Apple Watch Guidelines and found only this line:

> A raise of the wrist shows the time and new alerts.

I have an idea, to create my own app for iWatch, that would only display current time in particular way.

Is that possible for wearer to see my Glance View with only raising of the wrist and looking at the watches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Technology](https://www.apple.com/uk/watch/technology/) page

> We optimised your favourite apps for the wrist by developing Glances — scannable summaries of the information you seek out most frequently. To see them, you simply swipe up from your watch face.

Answer (score 0):

At this time. I didn't see anything said that wearer can see the Glance View with only raising of the wrist and looking at the watches. So I think the answer is NO. May be in the future, it can be change. when you make your watch application with glance view. The user will choose which application's glance view that they want to show up. And I think they have to take some action to see the glance scene.